# How to use of between operator in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
var conditionalData = {
    id: {
        $Between: [11, 15]
    },
    technician_id: technicianId
};
var attributes = ['id', 'service_start_time', 'service_end_time'];
userServiceAppointmentModel.findAll({
    where: conditionalData,
    attributes: attributes
}).complete(function (err, serviceAppointmentResponse) {
    if (err) {
        var response = constants.responseErrors.FETCHING_DATA;
        return callback(err, null);
    } else {
        if (serviceAppointmentResponse.length > 0) {
            var response = constants.responseErrors.NO_AVAILABLE_SLOTS_IN_YOUR_CALENDAR;
            return callback(response, null);
        }
    }
);
```

When I run the above query it gives me error as

> "message": "ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST: FUNCTION user_service_appointment.id
>   does not exist"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$Between` should be `$between`.

If you are using an **older version** of sequelize, you may need to remove the `$` too

Comment: Thanks . I used 2.0.3 version of sequelize